# How to turn off recalculate option in excel using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, epplus

I need some help.

I have this very simple code: http://pastebin.com/xc9xNHLQ

The issue I'm having is that every time I open the spreadsheet and try to close it, I'm being asked to save changes without making any changes.

I know the issue is in the SUM formula but is there a way of disabling that?

Using EPPLU and Studio 2015

Thanks

Comment: It seems there is a `FullCalcOnLoad` property on the workbook. Have you checked if it's set to true and tried setting it to false?

Comment: setting it to false did not make any difference. Still being asked to save changes.

Answer (score 1):

must using

```
package.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Manual;
```

and for calculating manually call:

```
package.Workbook.Calculate();
```

**UPDATE:**
from comment of 'Charles Mager' and this post, you can set FullCalcOnLoad to false then calculate manually. this is your manipulated sample code:

```
        package.Workbook.FullCalcOnLoad = false;
        worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 2].Value = "Total:";
        worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 3].Formula = "SUM(C12:C" + (RowNumber - 1) + ")";
        worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 2, RowNumber, 3].Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
        worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 2, RowNumber, 3].Style.Font.Size = 12;
        worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 2, RowNumber, 3].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        worksheet.Row(RowNumber).Height = 20;
        worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 2, RowNumber, 3].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        worksheet.Calculate();
        package.Save();
```

Comment: great. will give both a go and report back.

Comment: sadly does not work the way I wanted. Does not ask to save it anymore but then content of my cell is blank. I think I will need to store it in an incremental integer rather then using SUM. Thanks for both suggestions.

Comment: It worked for me. Just remember you have to call `Calculate()` AFTER you add the data to the sheet.

Comment: does not seem to work for me. This is what I have currently. http://pastebin.com/tV6ADQx8

Comment: @Tom, I use `package.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Manual;`, not `package.Workbook.FullCalcOnLoad = false;`

Comment: @VDWWD great stuff. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.